# How to use where_not_in() with two conditions in Codeigniter active records?

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I have written a search function in codeigniter using active records. What I want to do is if the payment_type = 5 and in the same record order_status = 1, then I want to omit it. But there can be records which payment_type = 5 and order_status = 2. if and only both conditions are satisfied have to omit that record. (payment_type = 5 AND order_status = 1). I have added the model function below. I want to know how to do this using active records. If anyone have any idea that will be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

```
public function getSalesByStore($from,$to,$status,$filter_stores,$offset, $amount, $limit = '')
    {
        $result = array();
        $this->db->select("*,a.created AS order_created,store_name, users.name, a.id as orderid, a.payment_type AS payment");
        $this->db->from("$this->table a");
        $this->db->join('users', "a.customer_id = users.id");
        $this->db->join('stores', "a.store_id = stores.id");
        $this->db->order_by("a.id", "desc");  


        if(!empty($status))
        {
            if ($status == 6)
            {
                $this->db->where('order_status != 3');
            }
            elseif ($status == 1) 
            {
                $this->db->where("a.payment_type != 5 AND order_status = $status");
            }
            else
            {
                $this->db->where('order_status', $status);    
            }
        }

        if(!empty($filter_stores))
        {
            $this->db->where('store_id in ('.$filter_stores.')');
        }
        if(!empty($from))
        {
            $this->db->where('date(a.created) >=', date($from));
        }
        if(!empty($to))
        {
            $this->db->where('date(a.created) <=', date($to));
        }
        if(!empty($amount))
        {
            if ($amount == 1)
            {
                $this->db->where("a.total_amount <=", 50);
            }else if ($amount == 2)
            {
                $this->db->where("a.total_amount >=", 50);    
            }      
        }
        $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
        {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row)
            {
                $row->order_status = $this->get_status($row->order_status);
                $result [] = $row;
            }
        }

        return $result;

    }
```

Comment: look here https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data  for `$this->db->where_in()` and `$this->db->where_not_in()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
<?php
public function getSalesByStore($from,$to,$status,$filter_stores,$offset, $amount, $limit = '')
    {
        $result = array();
        $this->db->select("*,a.created AS order_created,store_name, users.name, a.id as orderid, a.payment_type AS payment");
        $this->db->from("$this->table a");
        $this->db->join('users', "a.customer_id = users.id");
        $this->db->join('stores', "a.store_id = stores.id");
        $this->db->order_by("a.id", "desc");  


        if(!empty($status))
        {
            if ($status == 6)
            {
                //$this->db->where('order_status != 3');

                $this->db->where_not_in("order_status",'3');
            }
            elseif ($status == 1) 
            {
               // $this->db->where("a.payment_type != 5 AND order_status = $status");

                 $this->db->where("order_status","$status");
                $this->db->where_not_in("a.payment_type",'5');
            }
            else
            {
                $this->db->where('order_status', $status);    
            }
        }

        if(!empty($filter_stores))
        {
           // $this->db->where('store_id in ('.$filter_stores.')');

           $this->db->where_in('store_id',"$filter_stores");
        }
        if(!empty($from))
        {
            $this->db->where('date(a.created) >=', date($from));


        }
        if(!empty($to))
        {
            $this->db->where('date(a.created) <=', date($to));
        }
        if(!empty($amount))
        {
            if ($amount == 1)
            {
                $this->db->where("a.total_amount <=", 50);
            }else if ($amount == 2)
            {
                $this->db->where("a.total_amount >=", 50);    
            }      
        }
        $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
        {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row)
            {
                $row->order_status = $this->get_status($row->order_status);
                $result [] = $row;
            }
        }

        return $result;

    }
?>
```

Comment: In the way what you suggest if $status !empty only i can get the correct output. I want to get the correct output when the status is empty and not empty as well.

Comment: may be !empty would be correct condition for your code

Answer (score 1):

I have not checked this code but this might be the answer you're looking for

```
public function getSalesByStore($from,$to,$status,$filter_stores,$offset, $amount, $limit = '')
{
    $result = array();
    $this->db->select("*,a.created AS order_created,store_name, users.name, a.id as orderid, a.payment_type AS payment");
    $this->db->from("$this->table a");
    $this->db->join('users', "a.customer_id = users.id");
    $this->db->join('stores', "a.store_id = stores.id");
    $this->db->order_by("a.id", "desc");
    $this->db->where_not_in("a.payment_type",5); 
    $this->db->where_not_in("order_status",1); 


    if(!empty($status) && !empty($filter_stores)){
        if ($status == 6){
            $this->db->where_not_in('order_status',3);
        }
        else{
            $this->db->where('order_status', $status);    
        }
    }
    if(!empty($filter_stores)){
        $this->db->where('store_id in ('.$filter_stores.')');
    }
    if(!empty($from)){
        $this->db->where('date(a.created) >=', date($from));
    }
    if(!empty($to)){
        $this->db->where('date(a.created) <=', date($to));
    }
    if(!empty($amount)){
        if ($amount == 1){
            $this->db->where("a.total_amount <=", 50);
        }else if ($amount == 2){
            $this->db->where("a.total_amount >=", 50);    
        }      
    }
    $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row){
            $row->order_status = $this->get_status($row->order_status);
            $result [] = $row;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Even thought this is not the exact answer this helped to get the answer.